# React - history.push redirect not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ajax, redirect, browser-history

I'm trying to make my page redirect after login by using `.then` type ajax. Everything's working except the `history.push()` command:

```
axios
  .post('http://localhost:8080/login', {
    email,
    password
  })
  .then((res) => {
    sessionStorage.token = res.data.token;
    const { sub } = JSON.parse(atob(res.data.token.split('.')[1]));
    sessionStorage.email = sub;
  })
  .then(() => history.push("/reservations"))
  .catch(() => setError(connectionError))
}
```

Instead of redirecting, it's logging in correctly but not changing the page. The page updates when I refresh, but still no redirect.
Not sure if it matters, but here's my routing:

```
<Route path="/reservations" exact component={Reservations}/>
```

Help much appreciated

Comment: There might be other issues but `.then(history.push("/reservations"))` is wrong. It should be `.then(() => history.push("/reservations"))`.

Comment: Hi, i am facing that same problem. Did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score 2):

There's something wrong with the syntax of the last `.then`. Shouldn't it be a callback method inside which you'll call `history.push`?

Something like this:

```
axios
  .post('http://localhost:8080/login', {
    email,
    password
  })
  .then((res) => {
    sessionStorage.token = res.data.token;
    const { sub } = JSON.parse(atob(res.data.token.split('.')[1]));
    sessionStorage.email = sub;
  })
  .then(() => history.push("/reservations"))
  .catch(() => setError(connectionError))
}
```

Comment: I tried this, but it still didn't redirect

Comment: Would you be able to replicate this over a Sample [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/fork/react) or [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-new)?

Answer (score 1):

I will add the answer from SiddAjmera, if history still doesn't work, you have to add a package history

npm install history

index.js

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import { Router } from "react-router";
import { createBrowserHistory } from "history";

export const history = createBrowserHistory();

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router history={history}>
    <App />
  </Router>,
  node
);
```

```
import {history} from "./index"
axios
  .post('http://localhost:8080/login', {
    email,
    password
  })
  .then((res) => {
    sessionStorage.token = res.data.token;
    const { sub } = JSON.parse(atob(res.data.token.split('.')[1]));
    sessionStorage.email = sub;
  })
  .then(() => history.push("/reservations"))
  .catch(() => setError(connectionError))
}
```

Comment: I'll try this, but I'm using `useHistory` from `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 0):

**Try it this way:**

```
axios
      .post('http://localhost:8080/login', {
        email,
        password
      })
      .then((res) => {
        sessionStorage.token = res.data.token;
        const { sub } = JSON.parse(atob(res.data.token.split('.')[1]));
        sessionStorage.email = sub;
        history.push("/reservations");
      })
      .catch(() => setError(connectionError))
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Change `.then(history.push("/reservations"))` to `.then(() => history.push("/reservations"))`.